# Creating step function with error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a box or step function using if/else statements. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def V(x):
    if -1<=x<=1:
        return 20
    else:
        return 0
x=np.linspace(0,100)

plt.plot(x,V(x))
```

However, I get the error :

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I understand that this is because it is trying to compare all the x input values at once and cannot do so, but I don't understand why it doesn't just do one at a time and output the value for each. Indeed If i input just one x at a time it works. Is there an easy way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` to apply your function to each value of `x`:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100)
plt.plot(x, list(map(V, x)))
```

The reason for your error is you are attempting to apply a function on an entire array, when it is designed to work on a single element.

However, a better idea is to vectorise your function:

```
def V(x):
    res = np.zeros(len(x))
    res[np.where(np.abs(x)<1)] = 20
    return res

x = np.linspace(0, 100)
plt.plot(x, V(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through x, apply V(x) to each value, and save each value in an array.

```
y = np.zeros(len(x))
for i,j in enumerate(x):
   y[i] = v(j)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: or use list comp: `y = [V(item) for item in x]`