# Integration with upper boundary as independent variable

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to define a function with the independent variable as upper boundary of the integral:

```
from scipy import integrate

def integr(x):
    f = lambda y: 1 #example function
    value,_ = integrate.quad(f, 0, x)
    return value
```

Evaluating `integr` for a single number works. However, if I want to apply it to an array to receive a result array, a Value error is returned:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Do you know a solution for this? Do I need to make a loop over the values of the input array?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453418/creating-step-function-with-error-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-on).

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100) #example array
list(map(integr, x)))
```

Sorry for asking such simple questions, but I'm new with Python.